# extracting "throw new exception" into a method causes compile error

Tags: java, exception, refactoring

I have the following function:

```
private Box retrieveBox() {
    BoxParameter param = new BoxParameter("red", 10, 5, 3);
    List<Long> boxIds = boxDao.retrieveByParameter(param);

    if (boxIds.isEmpty()) {
        // A
        logger.warn("box not found");
        throw new BoxNotFoundException();
    }
    if (boxIds.size() > 1) {
        // B
        logger.warn("multiple boxes found");
        throw new MultipleBoxesFoundException();
    }

    Optional<Box> maybe = boxDao.retrieve(boxIds.get(0));
    if (maybe.isPresent()) {
        return maybe.get();
    }

    // C
    logger.warn("box not found");
    throw new BoxNotFoundException();
}
```

When I try to refactor the logging and exception into a method called `logWarningAndThrowException()`, I found that:

- A and B can be refactored
- if C is extracted into a method, Eclipse prompts that "This method must return a result of type Box"

I'm wondering the reason for that.

Is there a way to extract C into a method?

Comment: Without seeing your refactored code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: i've asked the question on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129976/throwing-exceptions-if-there-is-not-exactly-one-box-retrieved) from a code review perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any method with a return type except `void` must return a value of that type or throw an exception to end method execution.

In your current state your method will throw an exception to end method execution but if you move `C part` to another method then your `retrieveBox` method must return a value of type `Box` for a normal completion.

Hence eclipse is complaining.